# How can I put a "read more" link at each individual search result?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to put a "read more" link at each individual search result to view the full record. I guess I need to link to another file, like *fullview.php*. I guess I can solve that - the problem is how to code to get the "read more"-links.
Sorry for the layout/coding. I'm a newbie :-/

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("X", "Y", "Z") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"X") or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES UTF8");

$query = $_GET['query']; 
$min_length = 3;

if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) {
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $raw_results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Library WHERE (`Tablettes` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Title` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Author` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Language` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Subject` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Subject2` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `Translation` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `About` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY Lopnr ASC") or die(mysqli_error());

    if (mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {
        while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)) {
            $link = '';
            if (! empty($results['Link']) ) {
                $link = '<em><a href='.$results['Link'].'>Follow link here</a></em>';
            }

            echo "<p><table bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='900' align='center' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0' border='0'>

            <thead>
                <hr align='center' width='900'>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <tr><center><font color='#ffffff'>
                     Library: <strong>".$results['Library']."</strong></br><tr><center>".$results['CategoryYear']."
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style='border-right:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;border-top:none' colspan='10' valign='top'>
                        <em>
                        $link
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </body>
            </html>
            </table>";
        }
    } else { 
        echo "No results";
    }
} else {
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just realized that I could not easily code the fullview.php (or view_library.php). Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define file name of view more detail file with provide id of library by appending.

for example.

```
$link = '<em><a href="view_library.php?id='.$results['id'].' ">Follow link here</a></em>';
```

Here $results['id'] is primary key of library table (I am not sure about which primary key that you have set at the table).

Comment: Thanks. So I find out which is my primary key and then change 'id' to that key and it should work?

Comment: Yeah Primary key is unique and auto increment that is used to find all other fields detail of that table. So this key is unique.